# FORTRAN COMPILING ERROR

Tags: fortran

```
f77    -c -o alqueva.o alqueva.f
alqueva.f: In program `ssssss':
alqueva.f:402: 
           DO WHILE (.NOT. EOF(12))
                     1     2
.NOT. operator at (1) must operate on subexpression of logical type, but the subexpression at (2) is not of logical type
alqueva.f:415: 
                   DO WHILE (.NOT. EOF(iread))
                             1     2
.NOT. operator at (1) must operate on subexpression of logical type, but the subexpression at (2) is not of logical type
make: *** [alqueva.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Please format your code as code -- do you see the little icons above the editing window ?  Use the one composed of 1s and 0s.  Even without that I can spot your first mistake: FORTRAN77 is 30 years out of date.

Comment: BTW--Just posting an error listing like tat is not very friendly. You didn't even ask a question. Sure we were able to figure out that you don't know what to do with the above, but it would be polite to say so.

Comment: @High Performance Mark - FORTRAN77 is still heavily used in scientific and engineering disciplines (even prefered over later variants). Saying it's a mistake to use that, just because it's not the "new thing", is ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I did much fortran, but I don't believe that the `EOF` function is part of the standard for fortran 77, and I always used the end=label idiom

```
10 read (blah,end=20)
   process stuff
   goto 10
20 close (blah)
```

(but possibly using `do` instead of `goto`...)

[Here is page which discusses several options](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.fortran/browse_thread/thread/149d94a68d30fba3) including the above and one based on `iostat`